# Problem while testing a model. Anaconda function call stack error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, anaconda

I am trying to evaluate my deep learning RNN model but I keep getting this one error. I have absolutely no idea what the error means and I am unable to solve it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

This is the code I am using to evaluate my model:

```
model = keras.models.load_model('D:/Semester 3.2 OFFICIAL/Deep Learning/Assignment 2/test_model_14 files/Model14Checkpoint-188-0.60.h5')
model.load_weights('D:/Semester 3.2 OFFICIAL/Deep Learning/Assignment 2/test_model_14 files/Model14Checkpoint-188-0.60.h5')
evaluate = model.evaluate(X_test_seq_padded, y_test, batch_size=128)

loss = evaluate[0]
acc = evaluate[1] * 100
print("Loss: {:0.3f} - Accuracy: {:0.3f}%".format(loss,acc))
```

And this is the error that it returns:

```
128/8510 [..............................] - ETA: 1:05
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-8b3cba2991da> in <module>
     13 model = keras.models.load_model('D:/Semester 3.2 OFFICIAL/Deep Learning/Assignment 2/test_model_14 files/Model14Checkpoint-188-0.60.h5')
     14 model.load_weights('D:/Semester 3.2 OFFICIAL/Deep Learning/Assignment 2/test_model_14 files/Model14Checkpoint-188-0.60.h5')
---> 15 evaluate = model.evaluate(X_test_seq_padded, y_test, batch_size=128)
     16 
     17 loss = evaluate[0]

~\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size, verbose, sample_weight, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    928         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    929         workers=workers,
--> 930         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    931 
    932   def predict(self,

~\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in evaluate(self, model, x, y, batch_size, verbose, sample_weight, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    488         sample_weight=sample_weight, steps=steps, callbacks=callbacks,
    489         max_queue_size=max_queue_size, workers=workers,
--> 490         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    491 
    492   def predict(self, model, x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None,

~\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in _model_iteration(self, model, mode, x, y, batch_size, verbose, sample_weight, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    473               mode=mode,
    474               training_context=training_context,
--> 475               total_epochs=1)
    476           cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, result, mode)
    477 

~\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    126         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    127       try:
--> 128         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    129       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    130         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     96     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     97     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 98                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     99 
    100   return execution_function

~\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    566         xla_context.Exit()
    567     else:
--> 568       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    569 
    570     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

~\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    636               *args, **kwds)
    637       # If we did not create any variables the trace we have is good enough.
--> 638       return self._concrete_stateful_fn._filtered_call(canon_args, canon_kwds)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    639 
    640     def fn_with_cond(*inner_args, **inner_kwds):

~\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1609          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1610                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1611         self.captured_inputs)
   1612 
   1613   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1690       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1691       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1692           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1693     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1694         args,

~\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    543               inputs=args,
    544               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 545               ctx=ctx)
    546         else:
    547           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

~\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  indices[28,27] = 10792 is not in [0, 10000)
     [[node sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-8-8b3cba2991da>:15) ]]
     [[sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup/_17]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  indices[28,27] = 10792 is not in [0, 10000)
     [[node sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-8-8b3cba2991da>:15) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_distributed_function_8770]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup/7696 (defined at C:\Users\acer\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\contextlib.py:112)

Input Source operations connected to node sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup/7696 (defined at C:\Users\acer\anaconda3\envs\three point seven\lib\contextlib.py:112)

Function call stack:
distributed_function -> distributed_function
```

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working. It could also be helpful to look up how to create a [MCVE] - consider trimming out code that's not directly related to the problem.